# saving a text file in client side without asking for permission any time

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, client-side, text-files

I need to save a text file on the client side possibly without permission. The case is that I need to save this text file in a shared folder in this or in another machine in the lan. This text file is going to be read automatically by the fiscal printer which will print the fiscal invoice. I have a asp .net web application and the server is not on the same lan with the fiscal printer, so I have to write it on the client-side. Any idea how to do this without asking to the user every time for the security issue.
I need a cross browser solution.

I can accept a solution like, the client is asked only one time a the first printing, but not every time he wants to print a bill. Some kind of asking permission to the client for allowing this website, in order to not repeat the permission asking.

Comment: So you want to find a way to save a file on a user's computer without their knowledge?  And then you want an unrelated program to read this file?  Yeah, I don't think using a web browser for this task is the right way to go.

Comment: I am failing to see a reason why you can't do this server-side?

Comment: I can't do this server-side because we are talking about a ERP published in a public server outside the company that will use it.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously - this would be a major security breach to download files to the user's computer without them knowing. All browsers have precautions in place to prevent this from happening.

Comment: +1. If a Browser allowed this, there would be no way to prevent viruses from filling someone's computer.

Comment: I explained the case for this reason, don't miss understand me. I meaned that I don't want that user will be notified every time he prints a bill, or every time he logs in

Comment: At least it is possible to save a file in an [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) database without user interaction.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do this. Saving a file to a computer without permission in a public folder is not allowed.

You can, however, have your Client install your application which will have the ability to read and write where you want.

A common way that Trojan viruses to this is by giving the Client some goofy program to run that displays a fireworks show or something else quite trivial. While the Client is busy wondering what he's looking at, your virus is installing quietly in the background.

Now, you are probably saying to yourself, "But I am not installing a virus." However, there is no way for a Browser to know if your application is a virus or not. That is why it is not allowed and why you can not do it.

Comment: For me is ok if the permission is requested only one time, but not every time he wants to print a bill.

Answer (score 0):

The more applicable scenario for me is:

1- Do your work inside your web application.

2- Get the information that you need to print.

3- Send it to another computer directly (or to a hosted web service) and this computer will act as a host for these files.

4- let your server access this shared folder, and print what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie, which won't ask permission.  Of course that would only work when cookies are enabled and can store limited amounts of data.

Comment: I can't use cookies because i can't make the folder of the cookies shared